# How to install "Gradle support" plug-in in Spring Tools Suite 3.6.SR1?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tools Suite 3.6.SR1. I press menu Dashboard, press: "IDE EXTENSIONS"
Check "Gradle support", press Install:
[image]

[image]

> The following connectors are not available: Gradle Support Proceed
>   with the installation anyways?

[image]

```
Error:
Problems occurred while performing installation: Operation details
Operation details
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
```

Log:

```
!SESSION 2015-01-20 00:40:01.245 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2015-01-20 00:41:39.394
!MESSAGE Authorization infrastructure (org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth) not installed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth.AuthorizationDatabase cannot be found by org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.10.0.v20140318-2214
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AuthorizationHandler.getAuthClass(AuthorizationHandler.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AuthorizationHandler.loadKeyring(AuthorizationHandler.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AuthorizationHandler.flushAuthorizationInfo(AuthorizationHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.flushAuthorizationInfo(Platform.java:590)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.commons.ui.MigrateToSecureStorageJob.migrateToSecureStorage(MigrateToSecureStorageJob.java:89)
    at com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.internal.commons.ui.MigrateToSecureStorageJob.runInUIThread(MigrateToSecureStorageJob.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-01-20 00:41:43.092
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-01-20 00:41:43.094
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\vy.vy-pc'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:45:47.878
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:47:30.235
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:49:52.886
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:49:53.656
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:49:54.632
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:49:55.608
!MESSAGE Failed to dispatch repository event to org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.EclipseRepositoryListener: null

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:50:41.291
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 00:50:41.560
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 01:01:35.419
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 01:01:35.447
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 01:01:52.783
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2015-01-20 01:01:52.787
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui 4 0 2015-01-20 01:06:12.209
!MESSAGE Problems occurred while performing installation: Operation details
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Operation details
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.discovery.ui.PrepareInstallProfileJob.resolveInstall(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.discovery.ui.PrepareInstallProfileJob.run(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Contains: Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2015-01-20 01:06:12.211
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 10050 2015-01-20 01:06:12.211
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui 4 0 2015-01-20 01:08:28.519
!MESSAGE Problems occurred while performing installation: The following connectors are not available: Gradle Support (id=org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4), Groovy 2.2 Compiler for Groovy-Eclipse (id=org.codehaus.groovy22.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4)
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The following connectors are not available: Gradle Support (id=org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4), Groovy 2.2 Compiler for Groovy-Eclipse (id=org.codehaus.groovy22.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.discovery.ui.PrepareInstallProfileJob.checkForUnavailable(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.discovery.ui.PrepareInstallProfileJob.computeInstallableUnits(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.discovery.ui.PrepareInstallProfileJob.run(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui 4 0 2015-01-20 01:08:28.520
!MESSAGE The following connectors are not available: Gradle Support (id=org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4), Groovy 2.2 Compiler for Groovy-Eclipse (id=org.codehaus.groovy22.feature.feature.group, site=http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4)


    at ...
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
```

Comment: Might be a network issue. I tried this again with a fresh STS 3.6.3.SR1 installation and adding the Gradle extension works here. Can you access update sites via the "Install New Software" dialog? If so, you can go there and add the Gradle extension manually by selecting the STS update site from there.

Comment: Yes, I also use "Install New Software".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated Link** *as of 2-Jan-2018* : [Eclipse Gradle Integration](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration)

I go to: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44

Drag and drop **Install** button to Spring Tool Suits, then install.
Now I able create new Gradle Project in Spring Tool Suits:
[image]

Comment: That link is dead. Please update it with the one that works